# Ошибка при чтении символов из строки

Tags: c++

Пытаясь делать курсовую работу, застрял вот на таком моменте:

[image: ...]

Вот скриншот консоли на каком месте остановилась программа:

[image: ...]

Я делаю решение системы линейных уравнений и думаю, что ошибка кроется в cout и cin, а именно в буфере ввода. Как я понял из информации в интернете, это происходит из-за того, что в нём остаётся символ `\n` и от этого все проблема, но это не точно.

Когда убираешь `<<z<<` и остаётся просто: `"Введите коэффициенты неизвестных уравнения через ;" << endl;` - то программа продолжает работать и после ввода
коэффициентов, и вывода следующего cout опять та же ошибка. Уже пробовал всякие
`cin.sync()` и `cin.clear()`, но ничего не изменилось. Помогите пожалуйста и объясните как исправить.

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<locale.h>
#include<curand.h>
#include<curand_kernel.h>
#include<time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

__global__ void vichislenie( int *index, float *mas, int *kolvoperem )
{
    int indexGPU = threadIdx.x + *kolvoperem - 1 ;
    //for
    //while (index < 33792)
    //{
    /*if (*number < mas1[index])
        *otvchislo = 0;*/
    //index += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    //}
}
/*float *randomer(float *mas)

{
for (unsigned short i = 0; i < 33792; i++)
    mas[i] = 0.01 * (rand() % 10100);


return mas;
}*/




int main( void )
{
    setlocale( LC_ALL, "RUS" );
    unsigned short kolvostrok = 0;
    int kolvoperem = 0;
    int index = 0;
    float *masOtvet = new float[kolvostrok];
    cout << "Введите кол-во неизвестных переменных:  ";
    cin >> kolvostrok;
    cout << "Введите кол-во уравнений:  ";
    cin >> kolvoperem;
    cout << "Введите правые части уравнений:  ";

    for( unsigned short i = 0; i < kolvostrok; i++ ) {
        cin >> masOtvet[i];
        cin.sync();
        /*cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cin.clear();
        cin.get();*/
        //int dummy; my_cin(dummy);
    }

    index = kolvostrok * kolvoperem;
    float *masKoefic = new float[index];

    for( unsigned short i = 0; i < index ; i++ ) {
        masKoefic[i] = 0.0;
    }

    char *str = new char[kolvoperem * 2 * kolvostrok * 16];

    for( unsigned short i = 0; i < ( strlen( str ) ); i++ ) {
        str[i] = ' ';
    }

    unsigned short schetchik = 1;
    unsigned short schetchik1 = 0;
    char *StrBufMas = new char[kolvoperem * 2 * 16];

    for( int z = 1; z < kolvostrok + 1; z++ ) {
        /*cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cin.clear();
        cin.get();*/
        cout << "Введите коэфициенты неизвестных уравнения "
             << z << " через ;" << endl;
        cout << "(если в уравнении не полное кол-во переменных, то вместо них поставить нули): "
             << endl;
        cin >> StrBufMas;
    }

    //scanf("%s", *StrBufMas);
    schetchik1 = 1;

    for( unsigned short i = 0; i < kolvoperem * 2 * kolvostrok * 16; i++ ) {
        if( ( str[i + 1] ) == ' ' ) {
            if( schetchik1 == 1 ) {
            }
            else {
                break;
            }

            for( unsigned short i = 0; i < strlen( StrBufMas ); i++ ) {
                str[i + schetchik] = StrBufMas[i];

                if( i == ( strlen( StrBufMas ) ) - 1 ) {
                    schetchik = schetchik + strlen( StrBufMas ) + 1;
                    schetchik1 = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*size_t t = 6;
    char s1[10] = " tttrrrrr";
    char *s2 = new char[1];
    strcpy(s2, (s1-t));*/
    delete [kolvoperem * 2 * 16] StrBufMas, StrBufMas = NULL;
    schetchik = 0;
    schetchik1 = 0;
    char StrBufMas1[16] = "";

    for( unsigned short i = 0; i < strlen( str ) - 1; i++ ) {
        if( ( str[i] == ' ' ) || ( str[i] == ';' ) ) {
            //i -= 1;
        }
        else {
            schetchik++;
            schetchik1++;

            /*char *StrBufMas = new char[schetchik1];
            StrBufMas[schetchik1 - 1] = str[i];*/
            //strcat(StrBufMas1, &str[i]);
            if( ( str[i + 1] == ' ' ) || ( str[i + 1] == ';' ) ) {
                strncpy( StrBufMas1, &str[i - schetchik1 + 1], schetchik1 );
                masKoefic[i - schetchik] = atof( StrBufMas1 );
                //StrBufMas1 = ;
                //delete[schetchik1] StrBufMas;
                schetchik1 = 0;

                for( unsigned char j = 15; j > 0; j-- ) {
                    StrBufMas1[j] = '\0';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    float *masAll = new float[index - 1 + kolvostrok];
    schetchik = 0;
    schetchik1 = 1;

    for( unsigned short i = 0; i < index - 1 + kolvostrok; i++ ) {
        if( i == ( index + schetchik ) / kolvostrok ) {
            masAll[i] = masOtvet[i - ( i * schetchik1 )];
            schetchik1++;
            schetchik = schetchik + index + kolvostrok;
        }
        else {
            masAll[i] = masKoefic[i];
        }
    }

    float *dev_mas;
    int *dev_index;
    int *dev_kolvoperem;
    cudaMalloc( ( void ** )&dev_index, sizeof( int ) );
    cudaMalloc( ( void ** )&dev_mas, sizeof( float ) );
    cudaMalloc( ( void ** )&dev_kolvoperem, sizeof( int ) );
    cudaMemcpy( dev_index, &index, sizeof( int ), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    cudaMemcpy( dev_mas, &masKoefic, index * sizeof( float ),
                cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    cudaMemcpy( dev_kolvoperem, &kolvoperem, sizeof( int ),
                cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    vichislenie << <1, kolvoperem >> > ( dev_index, dev_mas, dev_kolvoperem );
    //n = atoi(S.c_str())
    /*float number;
    cout << "Введите число k:  ";
    cin >> number;

    int otvchislo = 1;
    int *dev_otvchislo;
    float *dev_number;

    unsigned short i = 256;
    while (i != 0)
    {
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_otvchislo, sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_number, sizeof(float));

    cudaMemcpy(dev_otvchislo, &otvchislo, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_number, &number, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    float mas[33792];
    float *dev_mas1;
    randomer(mas);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_mas1, 33792 * sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(dev_mas1, &mas, 33792 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    vichislenie << <128, 128 >> > (dev_number, dev_otvchislo, dev_mas1);

    cudaMemcpy(&mas, dev_mas1, 33792 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(&otvchislo, dev_otvchislo, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(dev_mas1);
    cudaFree(dev_number);
    cudaFree(dev_otvchislo);

    i -= 1;
    }


    if (otvchislo == 1)
    {
    unsigned char otv[4] = "да";
    cout << "Число k больше всех чисел в матрице? -" << otv << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
    unsigned char otv[4] = "нет";
    cout << "Число k больше всех чисел в матрице? -" << otv << "\n";
    }*/
    system( "pause" );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `из-за того, что в нём остаётся символ \n и от этого все траблы` именно. Думаю там где вы читали в следующей строке и решение будет... И да, а зачем вы читаете строки а не сразу числа?

Comment: транслит, скриншоты, 8 пробелов перед `#include` Вы правда думаете, что в этом беспорядке кому-то интересно разбираться?

Comment: Мне кажется проще было бы использовать vector<vector<double> > для левой части и vector<double> для правой, а потом использовать алгоритм Гаусса при этом считывать данные из файлов... займет строк 50-80 и по времени выйдет где-то минут 20-30 если не меньше.

Comment: Извините за оффтоп, но вы серьезно делаете это всё еще и на гпу при помощи cuda??

Comment: @pavel: Всё что было в след. строках я применял и это не срабатывало. Строки читаю, потому что думал, что важно для задания  
как вводятся числа. Оказалось нет, а переделывать мне лень...

Comment: @StrangeOwl: Да

Comment: На будущее. Что получить хороший и быстрый ответ на свой вопрос(и не быть заминусованым) стоит во первый вырезать из кода всё лишнее оставив минимальный воспроизводимый пример. А во вторых использовать не скрины, а текст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кому интересно проблема РЕШЕНА.
Нужно было z сделать строкой и вот так:

```
char *strt = new char[10];  
for( unsigned char z = 1; z < kolvostrok + 1; z++ )   
{
itoa(z, strt, 10);  

    cout << "Введите коэфициенты неизвестных уравнения "  
         << strt << " через ;" << endl;  
    cout << "(если в уравнении не полное кол-во переменных, то вместо них поставить нули): "<< endl;   
    cin >> StrBufMas;
```

Comment: И ещё убрать #include<locale.h> и setlocale( LC_ALL, "RUS" ) - какая-то   
глюченная хрень

Answer (score 4):

Написана какая-то белиберда

```
unsigned short kolvostrok = 0;
...
float *masOtvet = new float[kolvostrok];
```

Это выделение памяти под массив размера `0`.

После чего делается чтение данных в

```
cin >> kolvostrok;
...
for (unsigned short i = 0; i < kolvostrok; i++)
{
   cin >> masOtvet[i];
   ...
```

где `kolvostrok` уже не `0`. Разумеется, все будет падать из-за попытки записывать что-то за пределы массива нулевого размера.

Зачем вы вообще пытаетесь выделять массив нулевого размера? Может надо было *сначала* прочитать конкретное значение переменной `kolvostrok` и только *после этого* выделять память для `masOtvet`?

---

Кстати, а вот это что за сюрреализм

```
delete [kolvoperem * 2*16] StrBufMas
```

? Майкрософтовский компилятор поддерживает этот синтаксис (игнорируя значение выражения), но вам-то оно зачем сдалось?

Comment: И не лень вам было это читать!..

Comment: @VladD: Вот эта вот странная ошибка - иррациональная вера в то, что изменение значения переменной каким-то магическим образом задним числом приведет к изменению размера уже выделенного массива (как в варианте с `new`, так и в варианте с VLA) - по какой-то необъяснимой причине встречается очень часто в коде у начинающих (в частности, на cyberforum.ru). Поэтому она мне бросается в глаза. Такое впечатление, что где-то гуляет "методичка" с такой ошибкой.

Comment: Это то да, но главная ошибка не в этом.  
P.S. Спс, что увидели, я  не заметил этого.

Comment: @AnT: По моему это не игнорится и нормально всё делается, а выражение для увеличения места под пробелы и отрицательные и вещественные числа.

Comment: @Daunich: Тут нет никакого "по-моему". В языке С++ синтаксис delete-выражения для массивов - это именно `delete []`. Никакого выражения внутри `[]` не допускается. Майкрософтовский компилятор зачем-то разрешает указывать там выражение (если включены расширения языка), но его результат все равно игнорируется. (Возможно это наследие какой-то старинной черновой версии стандарта языка.)